# Unexpected Null Reference Exception on a DataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex property

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

Is it possible for a `DataGridView.CurrentCell` property to be not `null` and yet have a `null` value on its `RowIndex` property?
If so, how could I go about preventing this?

Extra info:
This value is beign checked on a `SelectionChanged` event for the `DataGridView` to keep the currently selected row's index stored in a class field.

Code is as follows:

```
private void dgTraffic_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (dgReport.CurrentCell != null)
            actualRow = dgReport.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
    #if DEBUG
        MessageBox.Show("Error on dgTraffic_SelectionChanged:\n" + ex.Message);
    #endif
    }
}
```

Somehow I got an unhandled NullReferenceException at the line that references the RowIndex property, so I added the try-catch but I can't figure out how could that happen.
By the way, I realize the method name says "dgTraffic" and the object used in the method's body reads dgReport. It is in fact set like that, this is the method being used for dgReport's SelectionChanged event.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: `DataGridView.RowIndex` is a non-nullable `int`, so no. It's likely that `CurrentCell` is actually `null`, however. You should check this before accessing its `RowIndex` property.

Comment: If that code is correct, I'd wager that `dgReport == null`.

Comment: How could dgReport be null and still have dgReport.CurrentCell be not null?

Comment: Because the if statement would be throwing the exception.  Set a break-point or output the whole stack trace with line numbers.

Comment: I suppose that might be possible, but then how could the event be triggered in the first place?
The RowIndex is a DataGridView.CurrentCell property. Not a DataGridViewRow property.

Comment: Just because a `GridView` exists somewhere doesn't mean your pointer to it has been properly set up.